# Changing working directory inside a function

Tags: r, function, working-directory

I want to pass the directory name as the formal argument of the function. Inside the function, I want to change my working directory to the directory mentioned in formal argument.
The directory is currently inside my working directory.

Note:

`specdata` is the directory inside my current wd

code:

```
 x <-function(directory)
 {
 y<-file.path(getwd(),directory)
 setwd(y)
 }

 x(specdata)
```

This seems to be not working, I do not want to enter `"specdata"` as function argument.It should `not be in double quotes`.

Comment: What is your opposition to using `x("specdata")`?  Using the quotes is almost certain to be a simpler solution than coding a solution without the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't  know why you want to avoid the double quotes, as you did not explain the context. But if this is really what you need, then you can use non-standard evaluation to achieve this.

```
x <-function(directory) { 
  directory <- as.character(substitute(directory))
  y <-file.path(getwd(),directory) 
  setwd(y) 
  }
```

The use of `as.character(substitute())` is exactly how, for example, the function `library()` allows one to either have quotations or not (the actual line that does this in the library function is `package <- as.character(substitute(package))`.)

Comment: to avoid problems down the road, the function ought to include `orig_wd <- getwd(); on.exit(setwd(orig_wd))` as well.

Comment: @Benjamin I'm not sure I understand the need for that. Since the purpose of the function is its side effect of changing the working directory, undoing this effect on exit seems to defeat the purpose.

Comment: I suppose that depends on whatever else the function is doing. If this is a function you may call twice within the same program, it will likely fail on the second call. If the sole purpose is to change the working directory, then it isn't necessary.